# Is it possible to connect 2 geth node using 2 VPS using Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, geth-clique

I've running my geth node in vps server using ubuntu, first node is mining now. Now I have a new VPS server which is the second vps. How can I connect the first node to the other VPS server? Or I just run the second node on 2nd VPS and add the `admin.addPeer("Argument")` 
which came from the first node enode?

How about the `genesis.json` on second node? do I need to init it to first node?
Basicially the question here is how to connect 2 nodes with different VPS server?

Answer (score 0):

You can generally replicate a `geth` installation by

1. Gracefully shutting down geth

```bash
sudo systemctl stop geth
```

2. Copy over the node data (This might take a while)

```
scp firstUser@firstVps:/path/to/node/data /secondVps/path/to/node/data
```

3. Installing `geth` on second machine
4. (Optional) add nodes in each others trusted peer *So Romantic*
5. Starting geth on both machines and wait for sync

Comment: Thank you for your response mate. But still, Can I run a private blockchain with 2 vps 1 node each?

Comment: @LloydRamos yes just with your own genesis and disabling peer discovery with only StaticNodes i suggest you check this document out https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/peer-to-peer